# How to process the audio from WebRTC?

Tags: firebase, webrtc

I'm doing some stuff with webRTC and firebase.
like this 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/simple-webrtc-video-chat-using-firebase)

In some case, I want to do some processing real-time with the remote audio from the webRTC.

There is a way to use web audio API to process audio.
But i can't find where the audiobuffer is.

Is it possible to get the audio buffer from webRTC or firebase data ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const ac = new AudioContext();

pc.onaddstream = event => {
    const src = ac.createMediaStreamSource(event.stream);
    const processNode = ac.createXXXX(); // create Web Audio API process Node(ex: ac.createAnalyser(), ac.createGain(), ac.createDeray(), etc...)
    src.connect(proccesNode);
    processNode.connect(ac.destination);
};
```

But, onaddstream is old spec event handler. new spec event handler is ontrack.

```
pc.ontrack = evt => {
    // ...
    if(evt.track.kind !== 'audio') return; 
    const src = ac.createMediaStreamTrackSource(evt.track);
    const processNode = ac.createXXXX(); 
    src.connect(proccesNode);
    processNode.connect(ac.destination);
};
```